# flattening a list or a tuple in python. Not sure what the error is

Tags: python

```
def flatten(t):
    list = []
    for i in t:
        if(type(i) != list and type(i) != tuple):
            list.append(i)
        else:
            list.extend(flatten(i))
    return list
```

Here is the function that I've written to flatten a list or a tuple that looks something like

```
l = ((5, (1,2), [[1],[2]]))
```

when I do

```
flatten(l)
```

I expected to get a list

```
[5, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

but I instead get

```
[5, 1, 2, [[1], [2]]]
```

I am not really sure why this happens because

```
    else:
        list.extend(flatten(i))
```

this part of the code will retrieve the int inside the third element of the tuple which is [[1],[2]] by calling it recursively. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: `list = []` is the problem. Try not to shadow built-in names/functions like `list`, etc. That only leads to trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You've assigned the built-in `list` to a list instance in your function, so the type check no longer works properly for list objects.

You should use a different name for the accumulator list, say, `lst`:

```
def flatten(t):
    lst = []
    for i in t:
        if type(i) != list and type(i) != tuple:
            lst.append(i)
        else:
            lst.extend(flatten(i))
    return lst
```

OTOH, you could do both checks at once using `isinstance` which also ensures that the objects you're running your checks against are actually types:

```
...
if not isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
    ...
```

Comment: It would be better to use `isinstance`. That way you also get an exception if you accidentally shadowed a name.

Answer (score 2):

You masked the name `list`:

```
list = []
...
    if(type(i) != list and ...
```

`type(i)` is never going to be equal to `[]`.

Use a different name for your list:

```
result = []
```

You also want to use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of `type()` with equality tests:

```
def flatten(t):
    result = []
    for i in t:
        if not isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
            result.append(i)
        else:
            result.extend(flatten(i))
    return list
```

this would have told you much earlier that you were not comparing with a type:

```
>>> list = []
>>> isinstance(['foo'], (list, tuple))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

The exception is thrown because `[]` is not a type.

You could use a generator here to avoid the need to append or extend a new list object repeatedly. If you put the `isinstance()` type check *outside* the loop you can support non-sequences with the same function:

```
def flatten(t):
    if not isinstance(t, (list, tuple)):
        yield t
        return
    for i in t:
        yield from flatten(i)

result = list(flatten(some_sequence_or_single_value))
```