# Integer or list to list

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a value that may be formatted as an integer or a list into a list.

For example

```
      60 --> [60]
    [60] --> [60]
[55, 65] --> [55, 65]
```

If I just put the variable in brackets, it creates a 1D list from an integer, but creates a nested list if it already is a list. There are lots of ways to do this with if or try statements, but there must be an easy one-liner I'm overlooking?

The following function returns the desired value, but is a recursive function really the best way to do this?

```
def flatten(v):
    return flatten(v[0]) + (flatten(v[1:]) if len(v) > 1 else []) \
    if type(v) is list else [v]
```

Comment: The code you've posted won't work for integers.

Comment: @RajanChauhan if you `list(int)` it will show an error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something of this sort should do:

```
def func(obj):
     return obj if isinstance(obj, list) else [obj]
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's about as easy as it gets. I settled on a similar lambda function: `lst = lambda v: v if type(v) is list else [v]`

Comment: @Thomas909 I'll advise you stick with `isinstance` instead of `type(v) is ...`. One reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433037/flattening-a-list-or-a-tuple-in-python-not-sure-what-the-error-is/45433101#45433101

Comment: Thanks, although note your answer reads 'instance' rather than 'isinstance', but I knew what you meant.

Comment: @Thomas909 Thanks :)